# Call function when all of onload events finish inside of jQuery's $.each loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, each, onload

I'm using jQuery's $.each function to iterate through an array of images and preload them. I'm also using an onload event so that I can do additional functionality once an image has finished loading. How can I know once ALL the images are finished?

```
var array = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg"];

function preloadAndDoStuff(array) {
    $.each(array, function(i, url) {
        var img = new Image();

        img.onload = function() {
            /* Some functionality here
            * that is only possible when
            * an image has finished loading */

            console.log(img.src + " loaded");
        }

        img.src = url;
    });
}

preloadAndDoStuff(array);

// 1.jpg loaded
// 2.jpg loaded
// 3.jpg loaded
// 4.jpg loaded
```

In my example instead of having X amount of logs I just need one. If it means anything: the array's length will be constantly changing.

Comment: The secret to finding the duplicate question was to search for "jquery wait multiple onload" on Google. Took about ten seconds. It even finds other very similar posts if you want to pick and choose.

Comment: I googled all over but I guess I was using the wrong terminology. Thanks for this!